# Pandas concatenates drops 0 in a value containing two decimal places

Tags: python, pandas, concatenation

I have an Excel spreadsheet containing two columns. Column A has a mix of numbers and letters and column B contains numbers with two decimal places (ex: 745.10, 345.21). I format all the data in the spreadsheet as text, and then copy and paste into Notepad++ so that I remove any hidden ".
Next, I run a Python script to import into a Pandas dataframe (DF1). Following that for Column A only, I applied a lambda operation and a new dataframe (DF2) is created for the lambda result. I then used Pandas to concatenate both DF1 and DF2 into a new dataframe (DF3).

Upon inspection of DF3, I noticed that in column B after DF1 was concatenated, the 0 has been dropped from 745.10. It now appears as 745.1. How can I correct this?

Regards,
Gus

Comment: `pd.options.display.float_format = f'{:.2f}'`

Comment: Thank you Miguel.